# Order geom_boxplot by p value

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am using the following code.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(ggpubr)
 mtcars$carb <- as.factor(mtcars$carb)
 mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
 ggplot(mtcars) + 
     geom_boxplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, fill = am), 
         position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
     stat_compare_means(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, group = am), label = "p.format")
```

This results in this plot:
[image]

How can I order the pairs from low to high p value, so that the order on the x-axis becomes carb = 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 8, please?

Please note that I need to apply this to a larger dataset, so I need to sort using the p values, rather than something like `c(2,1,4,3,6,8)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feels like there should be a simpler and more elegant way than this solution but here goes.

The approach:

- create a list column where `am` and `mpg` are nested under `carb`
- filter for rows with only 2 unique levels for `am` (l == 2)
- run `t.test` and add a column with the p-value
- join `carb` and `pval` back to the original data
- order by `pval` and make `carb` a factor with levels in the desired order (by `pval`)
- now we can `ggplot`

Code. Note that I use `t.test` to compare means in both cases, so the p-values differ to yours which I think used wilcox test by default.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

mtcars %>% 
  select(carb, am, mpg) %>% 
  mutate(am = factor(am)) %>% 
  nest(am, mpg)  %>% 
  mutate(l = map_int(data, ~unique(.$am) %>% length)) %>% 
  filter(l == 2) %>% 
  mutate(pval = map_dbl(data, ~t.test(mpg ~ am, .)$p.value)) %>% 
  select(carb, pval) %>% 
  right_join(mtcars) %>% 
  arrange(pval) %>% 
  mutate(carb = factor(carb, levels = unique(.$carb)), 
         am = factor(am)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(carb, mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = am)) + 
  stat_compare_means(aes(carb, mpg, group = am), 
                     label = "p.format", 
                     method = "t.test")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! Works perfectly. Thank you so much!